# How do I get MethodInfo having a delegate type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a generic method that gets the delegate type as a parameter. This method is needed to create a delegate instance that I want to create dynamically using reflection.

```
public T Do<T>() { ... }; // where T is delegate type
```

That is, the user passes to the method his custom delegate type `deleage string CustomDelegate(string input)`, the method creates a lambda based on delegate data: `(string input) => "test"`, then creates a delegate instance, passes this lambda there and returns the instance to the user.

To do this, I first need information about the delegate: the return type and the types of parameters. If a delegate instance was passed to me, then I could get the information I needed like this `delegateInstance.Method`, but I only have the delegate type.

How do I get MethodInfo with only the delegate type?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. If `T` is a delegate type, then why aren't you adding a type constraint? Where are you trying to get info about `T`? Why would you even need it?

Comment: @DavidG hi! Added additional information to the question.

Comment: `typeof(T).GetMethod("Invoke")`.

Comment: What method are you expecting to get the methodinfo for?  You only have a delegate type, not an instance of it, so it's entirely possible there are no methods in the entire universe of that signature, or there could be a million, and in that case which one do you want?

Comment: Is the *arity* of the delegate known (how many parameters and whether it has a return or is `void`, ignoring the actual types of the parameters or return)?

Comment: I probably put it wrong, I need to get the delegate signature. @JeroenMostert This is what I need, thank you! Write it in the answers, I'll like it